# Chrome extension onResponseStarted

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to catch the `onResponseStarted` event.
But I get this error:
`Uncaught Error: Parameter 1 (filter) is required.`.

When I look this up in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onResponseStarted) I can't really see what I'm doing wrong.

> **onResponseStarted**
>
> Fired when the first byte of the response body is received. For HTTP
>   requests, this means that the status line and response headers are
>   available.
>
> **addListener**
>
> chrome.webRequest.onResponseStarted.addListener(function
>   callback)

This is my code:

```
chrome.webRequest.onResponseStarted.addListener(function(details){
    console.log(details);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to provide the [`filter`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#type-RequestFilter) and [`options`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#type-OnResponseStartedOptions) too.

Try doing it like:

```
chrome.webRequest.onResponseStarted.addListener(function(details){
    console.log(details);
},
{
 urls: ["<all_urls>"]
},
["responseHeaders"]);
```

Comment: You could add a quote from the docs: _"To register an event listener for a web request, you use a variation on the usual `addListener()` function. In addition to specifying a callback function, you have to specify a filter argument and you may specify an optional extra info argument."_

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#subscription:

> To register an event listener for a web request, you use **a variation** on the usual addListener() function. In addition to specifying a callback function, you have to specify a filter argument and you may specify an optional extra info argument.

Parameter 1 here does not refer to the first parameter of the addEventListener function, but the first parameter of the additional parameters of the addEventListener function.

In other words, it's the second parameter. And it needs to match the interface [RequestFilter](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#type-RequestFilter) which at minimal is an object with key `urls`.